# SQL: Return Column names where column contains a given Value

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

i was wondering if there was a command/stored proc i can run in SQL Server that will give me the names of columns that contain given data within a table.

So if i was to query, give me all the columns in this table, that contain the value 75. i wouldnt want the row. just the column name within the table... is this possible?

Comment: Are these all string columns? Do you need the list of column names to be dynamic, or are you okay with hard-coding them?

Comment: Seems like a flawed schema design in there somewhere. But you want to know if any row in the table has that volume, or will you be looking at a specific row when you do this?

Comment: it would need to be dynamic, as it would need to be run on different databases and tables. and they wouldnt all be string columns.. am i asking too much here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
-- input parameters (guessing on type for @value):

DECLARE 
  @schema SYSNAME = N'dbo', 
  @table  SYSNAME = N'z', 
  @value  VARCHAR(64) = '75';


-- now, inside the procedure body:

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'SELECT ''cols:'' + STUFF(''''';

SELECT @sql += N' 
  + CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM ' 
  + QUOTENAME(@schema) + '.' + QUOTENAME(@table)
  + ' WHERE TRY_CONVERT(VARCHAR(64), ' + QUOTENAME(c.name) 
  + ') = @value) THEN '', ' + c.name + ''' ELSE '''' END'
FROM sys.tables AS t
INNER JOIN sys.columns AS c
ON t.[object_id] = c.[object_id]
INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS s
ON t.[schema_id] = s.[schema_id]
WHERE t.name = @table AND s.name = @schema;

SET @sql += N', 1, 1, '''');'

PRINT @sql;

--EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N'@value VARCHAR(64)', @value;
```

When you are happy with the output, uncomment the `EXEC`.

So let's consider a simple table:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.floob
(
  a INT, 
  b VARCHAR(32), 
  c VARBINARY(22), 
  d DATE, 
  e DATETIME, 
  f ROWVERSION
);

INSERT dbo.floob(a,b,c,d,e) VALUES
( 75, 'foo', 0x00, GETDATE(), GETDATE()),
( 21, '75',  0x00, GETDATE(), GETDATE());
```

Now, a stored procedure based on the above code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.FindStringInAnyColumn
  @schema SYSNAME = N'dbo', 
  @table  SYSNAME,
  @value  VARCHAR(64)
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'SELECT ''cols:'' + STUFF(''''';

  SELECT @sql += N' 
    + CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM ' 
    + QUOTENAME(@schema) + '.' + QUOTENAME(@table)
    + ' WHERE TRY_CONVERT(VARCHAR(64), ' + QUOTENAME(c.name) 
    + ') = @value) THEN '', ' + c.name + ''' ELSE '''' END'
  FROM sys.tables AS t
  INNER JOIN sys.columns AS c
  ON t.[object_id] = c.[object_id]
  INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS s
  ON t.[schema_id] = s.[schema_id]
  WHERE t.name = @table AND s.name = @schema;

  SET @sql += N', 1, 1, '''');'

  EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N'@value VARCHAR(64)', @value;
END
GO
```

Sample usage:

```
EXEC dbo.FindStringInAnyColumn @table = N'floob', @value = '75';
```

Output:

```
Cols: a, b
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the above comments that it sounds like you have a suboptimal schema design. You will probably run into performance issues if you try to do this on a large data set.

That said, you could unpivot the columns to convert them to rows. Here is an example lifted verbatim from the [Using PIVOT and UNPIVOT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=SQL.105%29.aspx) article on Technet. Instead of 75, I used 4:

```
--Create the table and insert values as portrayed in the previous example.
CREATE TABLE pvt (VendorID int, Emp1 int, Emp2 int,
    Emp3 int, Emp4 int, Emp5 int);
GO
INSERT INTO pvt VALUES (1,4,3,5,4,4);
INSERT INTO pvt VALUES (2,4,1,5,5,5);
INSERT INTO pvt VALUES (3,4,3,5,4,4);
INSERT INTO pvt VALUES (4,4,2,5,5,4);
INSERT INTO pvt VALUES (5,5,1,5,5,5);
GO
--Unpivot the table.
SELECT VendorID, Employee, Orders
FROM 
   (SELECT VendorID, Emp1, Emp2, Emp3, Emp4, Emp5
   FROM pvt) p
UNPIVOT
   (Orders FOR Employee IN 
      (Emp1, Emp2, Emp3, Emp4, Emp5)
)AS unpvt
WHERE VendorID = 1 AND orders = 4;
```

This yields the following result:

```
+--+----------------------------------------+
|  | VendorID        Employee        Orders |
+--+----------------------------------------+
|  | 1               Emp1            4      |
|  | 1               Emp4            4      |
|  | 1               Emp5            4      |
+--+----------------------------------------+
```