# How can I return a result where the value exists but that value can be in anyone of 120 different columns in a single table

Tags: sql

I have a Table that contains 120 columns. I am pulling data where if a code say "xxx" exists in anyone of these columns. The issue I have is that value of "xxx" can be in anyone of the 120 columns depending on the data for that account. I want to return only that column that has that value. Because I am using a Select * from the table, it returns all 120 columns. So I am struggling to figure out a solution just to return only the column that the code "xxx' I am looking is in, instead of the whole table. NOTE: I cannot set a specific column name = 'xxx' because it can be in any of the columns.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

I have tried the query below and also another query where the below query is a sub query as "AND exist" the the query below

Example of my query

```
Select user_table.user_id, User_class.*
From user_table
Join user_class on user_class_id = user_class_id
Where user_id='xxxxxx'
And 'xxx' IN (col_1,col_2,col_3);
```

and so on for all 120 column

What I want in a return result is the User ID and the what ever column that has my value I an search for.

Comment: It sounds like you have a data modeling problem.  That data should probably be in separate rows, not columns.

Comment: Gordon so thats out of my control I am just trying to write a query to put in my automated test to verify and account has this specific value. I am not the DB designer.

Comment: Google for `PIVOT` and `DYNAMIC PIVOT` when you convert columns into rows you can do an easy search

Comment: Have a look here: [SQL: Return Column names where column contains a given Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20405322/sql-return-column-names-where-column-contains-a-given-value) :)

Comment: Juan, thank you i will look into this. I am not a super SQL expert so hopefully i will understand what and how to use the pivot / dynamic pivot. then hopefully i can get my desired results.

Comment: For clarity, you will need `UNPIVOT`, pivot convert rows into columns and you need columns into rows. And if columns are fixed wont need `DYNAMIC` so the examples you found should be straight forward. But Valerica link also look promising, you should try it if work on your rdbms

Comment: @ScottyR, @JuanCarlosOropeza that link also has an `UNPIVOT` solution

Answer (score 0):

You can try to write a very big case when statement. The case will break with first positive condition and you will always get only one column.

```
Select 
user_table.user_id, 
case 
   when col_1 = 'xxx' then col_1
   when col_2 = 'xxx' then col_2
   when col_3 = 'xxx' then col_3
   .
   .
   .
end as xxx_col
From user_table
    Join user_class on user_class_id = user_class_id
Where user_id='xxxxxx'
And 'xxx' IN (col_1,col_2,col_3);
```

If you want to identify which column actually had the value then you can repeat the same case statement again and have a string as result i.e.

```
case 
    when col_1 = 'xxx' then 'col_1 has value'
    when col_2 = 'xxx' then 'col_2 has value'
    .
    .
end as which_string
```

Comment: Nik, although that solution will actually get the results I am looking for but it is really long. I also have another option I can use is by using the "and exist" in my query and only returning my User id that would prove the code exists in that table but i just wont return that actual code value. If the return result is empty then i will know the code value I am searching for doesn't exist. I have to weight my options on how to tackle this.